# How to rewrite directive on apache for anchor cms

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a cms called anchor. 
http://anchorcms.com/docs/getting-started/configuration

when I go to domain.com/posts 
I get a 404,

when I go to domain.com/index.php/posts 
page is displayed correctly.

this is my `httpd.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
#ssl blah blah

DocumentRoot /var/www/anchor/
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com

<Directory /var/www/anchor/anchor/>
    AllowOverride All
    Options Includes MultiViews
    Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

this is my `.htaccess` file placed inside `/var/www/anchor/`

```
Options -indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

I'm a little confused as how to configure this cms, the .htcaccess supposed to go in the "document root", which I'm fairly sure I put in the correct folder. I don't think I have to set the url to a sub directory. any tips?

here's my config file. `/var/www/anchor/anchor/config/app.php`

```
<?php

return array(
        'url' => '/',
        'index' => '',
```

Comment: Your document root is `/var/www/anchor`, but you only allow overrides on `/var/www/anchor/anchor`. If you're not globally allowing overrides, that would disable your htaccess file. Try changing your `<Directory>` tag to match the document root.

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley could you please put this as an answer, I'll then edit it with the config I used to make it work. You were right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document root is `/var/www/anchor`, but you only allow overrides on `/var/www/anchor/anchor`. If you're not globally allowing overrides, that would disable your htaccess file. Try changing your `<Directory>` tag to match the document root:

```
<Directory /var/www/anchor>
    AllowOverride All
    Options Includes MultiViews
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I had to remove the "Options Includes Multiviews" line, because the custom htacces has a definition that overrides it.